# Создание экземпляра класса-наследника из экземпляра класса-предка

Tags: c#, наследование

Мне уже несколько раз приходилось сталкиваться с такой ситуацией:

Есть класс A, у которого есть какие-то public свойства.

Есть класс B, наследник A, у которого есть ещё какие-то свойства.

У меня есть заполненный экземпляр класса A, и мне нужно создать на его основе экземпляр класса B, в котором все унаследованные от A свойства заполнены значениями из существующего экземпляра A.

Простой каст вида:

```
B newB = (B)oldA;
```

как оказалось, не работает.

В общем, я пришёл к следующему решению:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Basis basis = new SubjectA()
        {
            something = "asd",
            whatever = 3
        };

        SubjectA subject = upgradeClass<Basis, SubjectA>(basis);

        Console.WriteLine(subject.something); // asd
        Console.WriteLine(subject.whatever);  // 3

        // and subject.moar is 0, because I didn't set value to it

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static T2 upgradeClass<T1, T2>(T1 basis) 
        where T1 : new()
        where T2 : T1, new()
    {
        T2 upgrade = new T2();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propT1 in basis.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo propT2 = upgrade.GetType().GetProperties().First(x => x.Name.Equals(propT1.Name));
            propT2.SetValue(upgrade, propT1.GetValue(basis));
        }

        return upgrade;
    }

    public class Basis
    {
        public string something { get; set; }
        public int whatever { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubjectA : Basis
    {
        public decimal moar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Пока что, насколько я могу судить, всё работает как должно.

**Вопрос**: какие могут быть проблемы у такого решения?

Comment: Изменение класса на дочерний - подозрительная ситуация сама по себе. Он может другую семантику иметь. У класса могут быть приватные поля, от которых зависит значение свойств. Свойства могут быть только для чтения.

Comment: @Monk, В данном случае, меня интересуют только public поля.

Comment: Если ваши классы всего лишь DTO, то возьмите AutoMapper, и не изобретайте велосипед.

Comment: Пробовали реализовать `explicit` и `implicit` операторы определить чтобы каст `B newB = (B)oldA;` работал?

Comment: Пример в твоем решении ужасен: если ты делаешь `Basis basis = new SubjectA(){...}` то тебе не нужен метод `upgradeClass`, достаточного обычного приведения типов: `SubjectA subject = (SubjectA)basis`

Comment: @Grundy это не работает. Я же сказал: `Простой каст вида:
B newB = (B)oldA;
как оказалось, не работает.`

Comment: @MrScapegrace, проверь еще раз. Я говорю именно про случай у тебя в примере. Если ты в коде примера заменишь строку `SubjectA subject = upgradeClass<Basis, SubjectA>(basis);` на `SubjectA subject = (SubjectA)basis;` то ничего не поменяется

Comment: @Grundy Хорошо, может быть, я привёл неудачный пример. В рабочем коде мне нужно копировать экземпляр класса, внутри которого есть списки и экземпляры других классов. Не знаю, что именно его не устраивает, но обычное приведение типа не работает.

Comment: @MrScapegrace, не имеет значения что нужно копировать, главное: как у тебя появляется этот объект и какой его реальный тип

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, проблемы возможны, конечно.

Навскидку: поля класса `T2` могут иметь одинаковые имена с полями класса `T1` (перекрытие полей).

```
public class SubjectA : Basis
{
    public new decimal whatever { get; set; }
}
```

приведёт к исключению.

Во-вторых, свойство класса `T1` может вовсе не иметь сеттера.

```
public class Basis
{
    public string something { get; } = "something";
    public int whatever { get; set; }
}
```

или он может быть объявлен приватным:

```
    public string something { get; private set; }
```

В-третьих, у базового типа может быть статическое свойство, которое приведёт к обрушению вашего метода:

```
public class Basis
{
    public string something { get; set; }
    public int whatever { get; set; }
    public static int gotcha { get; set; }
}
```

Затем, кроме свойств у базового класса могут быть какие-то важные поля, которые вы не учитываете.

Ну и напоследок, установка значения поля для достаточно сложных объектов может потребовать дополнительной логики для поддержания инвариантов вашего класса. Поэтому я бы использовал этот метод лишь для достаточно простых DTO-классов.

---

Я бы переписал метод в таком виде:

```
public static T2 UpgradeClass<T1, T2>(T1 basis)
    where T1 : new()
    where T2 : T1, new()
{
    T2 upgrade = new T2();
    for (Type t = basis.GetType(); t != null; t = t.BaseType)
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties(
                                         BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
            p.SetValue(upgrade, p.GetValue(basis));

    return upgrade;
}
```

В таком виде метод всё ещё не очень хорош.

Это решает проблему с конфликтами имён и статическими свойствами, но не решает проблему со свойствами без сеттера/с приватным сеттером, а также проблему полей. Приватный сеттер (и геттер) *можно* было бы вызвать через рефлексию тоже, но мне кажется это неправильным: если в семантике класса метод закрыт, значит, в нём может быть нетривиальная логика, которую нельзя вызывать в произвольный момент; а значит, не стоит «дёргать» его снаружи.